# how to run gcloud container command using api

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am using this gcloud command to resize my GKE cluster

```
   gcloud container clusters resize $CLUSTER_NAME --num-nodes=0
```

how can I achieve the same using the api? 
 
I found [@google-cloud/container](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/container) library, what function should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

```
const container = require('@google-cloud/container');
const client = new container.v1.ClusterManagerClient();

const request = {
    projectId: 'my-project-id',
    zone: 'us-central1-f',
    clusterId: 'my-cluster-id',
    nodePoolId: 'default-pool',
    nodeCount: 0
};

client.setNodePoolSize(request, (err, res) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

see also [api reference](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest)